# Build History Missing in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I just set up a new Jenkins instance for my project (Version 2.19.4). But when I try to generate several builds for testing I find that the Build History only shows me one historical build.

Before upgrading, it showed at least two or more. Is there a place in Jenkins I can set the number of historical builds which should show up?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the job configuration page you can set the number of historic builds to maintain in the history. You've probably got it set to 0. If you have admin rights on that job then you should be able to change that.

Comment: The option is at: job's config page -> `Discard old builds`

Answer (score 4):

In Jenkins configuration you can use "Discard Old Build" Plugin to keep history of builds.

[image]

And this configuration can be done for every job you have created.

To see details of Plugin and more different ways to use it click [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Discard+Old+Build+plugin)