# Missing build from jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I ran a build yesterday, hoping I would read some logs today.
I came today, and got an error 404 when trying to access the build. Strange.

Running another build, shows my build actually did run, but it is unreachable.

Is there a way to get my hands on the logs?

[image]

Notice build #10 is missing, even though it did start.

Probably a windows update is to blame for this.

---

The broken link is `http://192.168.80.10:8080/job/Dev_git/10`

Comment: I guess you already tried what I posted in my answer (which I will edit eventually). If yes - could you please edit your question and add parts of the console output, please? Also: At which exact Jenkins-URL did the 404 occur?

Comment: @B--rian Can't reach the console output, as the build I want does not exist. Edited the question.

Comment: I edited my answer, please let me know what the situation in the respective subfolder of `C:/MyJenkinsInstallation/jobs/` looks like.

Answer (score 0):

More information on a run can usually be found using the context menu under **Console Output**. This is only accessible if you have the correct permissions set in Jenkins.

[image: Jenkins Build History Context Menu]

This of course does not work, if a build is missing. One reason could be that your Jenkins is configured in a way that only a certain number of historic builds are kept, see [Build History Missing in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169736/build-history-missing-in-jenkins) for an explanation how to deal with that.

However, your case seems to be different, because a build in the middle of the history is missing. For this, I suggest to look around in the `jobs` directory of your Jenkins installation where it stores all the configuration and run data.

**References**

- https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins
- [Where does Jenkins store configuration files for the jobs it runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131114/where-does-jenkins-store-configuration-files-for-the-jobs-it-runs)